# Javascript check if it has passed midnight since a certain time

Tags: javascript, date, time

I need to create a javascript function that checks if it has been a day since timeX (an instance of Date).  I do NOT mean whether is has been 24 hours since timeX, but instead whether it has passed a midnight since timeX.

I am a PHP expert, not a JavaScript one, so I was wondering if anyone here had any quick answers.  Thanks!

```
function(dateLast, dateNow) {...}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple solution to check whether two dates represent the same day is:

```
function isSameDay(a, b) {
    return a.toDateString() == b.toDateString();
}
```

This works no matter what the distance between the two dates is.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(dateNow.getDate() == dateLast.getDate()){
 //it's the same day
}else{
 //another day, so midnight has passed
}
```

EDIT: changed the condition, now it should work.

Comment: Could be an error if the dates are exactly 1 month apart.  Almost though

Comment: What happens if the two dates are 2010-04-15 and 2010-05-15?